# Can I place my code in a viewmodel if that code has references to the view?

Tags: swift, viewmodel

I have a `view` with alot of logic code that would be better of in a `viewmodel`. The problem is that the code has references to the `view` which means that the `viewmodel` would need an object from the `view` to work properly. If I understand the concept of a `viewmodel` correctly, having a two-way dependency defeats the whole purpose of a `viewmodel`

As you can see from the code below it contains the line `addChild(x)` as well as `.removeFromParent`. So if moved to a `viewmodel` the code would have to be something like: `mainView.addChild(x)`. It works sure enough, but my question is if it's appropriate. If not, should I just keep the code in the view, even though it takes up alot of space and has alot of logic in it?

These functions are used in the native `touchDown()` function:

```
func characterIsSelected(i: Int, j: Int) {
    //Check Accessibility of Tile
    if !gameBoardArray[i][j].isAccessibilityElement {
        hasBeenClickedOnce = true
        characterIsSelected = true
        characterVM.getGameBoardPosition().fillColor = SKColor.brown
        print("NOT ACCESSIBLE")
        return
    }else {
        print("Moving")
        viewModel.placeCharacter(row: i, col: j)
        buttonIsAvailable = false

        //SEE HERE
        guiButton.removeFromParent()
        enemyProximityCheck(i: i, j: j)
    }
}

func enemyProximityCheck(i: Int, j: Int){
    print("ENEMY PROXIMITY")
    //SCAN VICINITY OF CHARACTER. IF ENEMY IS ON TILE, GOTO COMBAT
    for ii in -1...1 {
        for jj in -1...1 {
            //gameBoardArray[i + (ii)][j + (jj)].fillColor = SKColor.blue
            if(i + (ii) < 0 || j + (jj) < 0 ) {
                print("LOW")
            }
            else if(i + (ii) > gameBoardArray.count - 1 || j + (jj) > gameBoardArray.count - 1) {
                print("HIGH")
            }
            else {
                if (gameBoardArray[i + (ii)][j + (jj)].contains(enemyVM.getCurrentEnemyPosition() ) ) {
                    print("AAARGH AN ENEMY!")

                    //SEE HERE
                    addChild(guiButton)
                    buttonIsAvailable = true
                    //enemyHasBeenSpotted = true
                }
            }
        }
    }//End for
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if you’re using a “view model”, the view model would not generally be manipulating the view directly. It would simply communicate the “encountered enemy” (or whatever) event to the “view” (which many of us would consider to be both the `UIView` hierarchy and the view controller, too), which would then be responsible for manipulating the view(s) accordingly.

Unfortunately, it’s hard to say precisely how the view model would do this in your case, on the basis of what you’ve outlined. Some use the term “view model” loosely, so there are a couple of possible interpretations:

1. One approach is to have the view observe (through some “binding” mechanism) some property in the view model, and when the view model updates that state, the view would then add/configure the appropriate views/subviews accordingly. (This is binding/observing is arguably an essential aspect of any “view model” based approach.)
2. Other approaches include protocol-delegate or closure patterns for the view model to communicate that UI updates to the view. (This is arguably more of a MVP sort of approach, though I’ve seen teams use the term “view model” in this context, too.)

But the consistent pattern is that the view model should generally not be reaching in and manipulating the view hierarchy itself. It should simply communicate (one way or the other) the state change, and the “view” would take it over from there.

FYI, I think Medium’s [iOS Architecture Patterns](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-architecture-patterns-ecba4c38de52) is illuminating when talking about these various patterns in the context of iOS apps.

Comment: Thank you @Rob, I will check out the link and see if I can integrate one of your approaches. One more thing (if you are familiar with spritekit): is the GameScene.swift considered the view even though the GameViewController strictly speaking is the view directly linked to to UI? Or is GameScene.swift considered the viewModel?

Comment: The `GameScene` is also part of the “view”. The view consists of anything that participates in the manipulation of assets on the screen or directly responding to user input. The view model is something that can be tested in complete isolation of the screen/device. So, in a SpriteKit game, the “view” adds sprites to the screen and detects collisions. The “model” consists of things like what the score is, what level you’re on, etc. The “view model” is the mediator (e.g. when the view informs view model of collision, view model updates the model, instructs the view what it should do next, etc.).

Comment: As I suspected. Thank you for the well written clarification and your assistance! :)

Answer (score -2):

If you want to be a purist about MVC design, then game logic would go in the *controller*, not the view *or* the model. Their roles should be:

- model: The current state of the game; e.g. which characters are in which game board array slots. It knows nothing about the view or the controller.
- view: The visual representation of the game board. It reads from the model, but doesn't necessarily hold a reference to it.
- controller: The game logic. It responds to user actions by updating the model and telling the view to redraw itself based on the model. It has strong references to the view and the model.

That said, if your game logic is fairly simple, then separating things out into a model, view, and controller may be overkill. Most of the time, I start with a view controller class file and a corresponding view controller in a storyboard. If it gets too complex, then I create a view and/or model. The view controller has an outlet to the view, the view has outlets to its subviews, and the view's controls are connected to `IBAction`s in the view controller.

Comment: I didn’t down-vote, but when the OP introduced the term “view model”, that means that they’ve likely shifted away from MVC, and outlining a pattern without a “view model” will likely only cloud the discussion for Mark. Also, when you use the term “controller”, are you talking about the view controller, or are you using the term in the spirit of Dave DeLong’s [A Better MVC](https://m.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2188&v=YWVzCd5FYbs)?

Comment: My bad, I should have mentioned I intend to use MVVM. Still, thanks @NRitH, I will check out MVC as well. Maybe that's relevant for my project as well.